# Django query filter, return object if attr delete is false (i.e if it hasn't been deleted)

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have the following:

```
PHONE_CHOICES = (
    ('home', 'Home'),
    ('home2', 'Home 2'),
    ('mobi', 'Mobile'),
    ('mobi2', 'Mobile 2'),
    ('work', 'Work'),
    ('work2', 'Work 2'),
)

phones = []
for k, v in PHONE_CHOICES:
    try:
        phones.append(ClientPhone.objects.filter(client=clientKEY, phone_type=k).latest('id'))
    except ClientPhone.DoesNotExist:
        pass
```

I also have an attribute in `ClientPhone` called `deleted`. I only want it to append the most resent phone to the `phones` list if `deleted` is null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is somewhat difficult to tell what you are asking, but I think you want something like this:

```
phones = []
for k, v in PHONE_CHOICES:
    try:
        current = ClientPhone.objects.filter(client=clientKEY, phone_type=k)
        if current.deleted is None:
            phones.append(current.latest('id'))
    except ClientPhone.DoesNotExist:
        pass
```

Comment: Thanks, just what I was looking for! Python can sometimes help compress things that are usually long winded in languages like PHP, I was just wondering if this was one of those cases